# Diff two images with im4java and give the number of different pixels as result

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

I have two images which I want to compare with the ImageMagick Java wrapper 'im4java'. As far I have this piece of code:

```
boolean compare (String picture1, String picture2) {
    boolean pdfsEqual;
    IMOperation imOperation = new IMOperation();
    imOperation.metric("ae");
    imOperation.addImage();
    imOperation.addImage();
    imOperation.addImage();
    CompareCmd compare = new CompareCmd();
    ArrayListOutputConsumer outputConsumer = new ArrayListOutputConsumer();
    compare.setOutputConsumer(outputConsumer);
    try{
        compare.run(imOperation, pathSample, pathResult, "null:");
        pdfsEqual = true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        pdfsEqual = false;
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = outputConsumer.getOutput();
        System.out.println(stringArrayList);
    }
    return pdfsEqual;
}
```

But the `stringArrayList`  is empty. Reading `im4java` documentation I found that actually the `OutputConsumer` stores the output in an array list but as already said there is nothing. Also, `imOperation.metric("ae")` counts the pixels that are different between the two images and prints it to the console if the call has been done from command prompt itself. I can't figure out how I can get this number of diff pixels in my java code using the `OutputConsumer`.

Comment: I can't really read java, but have some experience of ImageMagick, but... have you actually added any images to compare - the parameters to `addImage()` look very empty to this C programmer.

Comment: `addImage()`  is just a placeholder for adding an image. The actually adding is done by `compare.run(IMOperation, Object ...objects)` where I give the paths to the images as second and third argument.

Comment: There may be a really simple solution to this, but I don't know Java and am just trying to help you get going, ok? Another idea for a workaround just to get you going is to use the `convert` program, rather than the `compare` program within ImageMagick. At the commandline, you can run this command instead of your`compare` command and get the same result... `convert -metric ae image1.png image2.png -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure, I am not against any hints=) Actually I could get the desired behavior on the command prompt and I get the counter for different pixels as output in the console but the problem is that I actually need to read this counter in java. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
ArrayListErrorConsumer and setErrorConsumer
```

instead of

```
ArrayListOutputConsumer and setOutputConsumer
```

I don't know why it appears in on the wrong consumer. Maybe it is a bug.